# Highcharts show blank colum with text

Tags: highcharts

[image]

Please see image, need to show title on `null`/`blank` column.

here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ws5ez0j9/4/

That I did it with Chart Title but thats not a way for it.

Need column `title` or something so It will display in Mobile view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically do this with the [load event](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) of highcharts and [annotations](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations). Like this:

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.series[0].data.length; i++) {
        if (this.series[0].data[i].y == null && this.series[1].data[i].y == null) {
          this.addAnnotation({
            labelOptions: {
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
              borderWidth: 0,
            },
            labels: [{
              point: {
                x: i,
                y: 0,
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0
              },
              text: 'Your title here',
              shape: 'rect',
              style: {
                fontSize: '20px'
              }
            }]
          })
        }
      }
      this.redraw()
    }
  }
},
```

This will print a text for every position in the chart that does not have any values.

It is assumed that you have two series, both with `null` values where data is missing. After a point with no data is found an annotation is added in its place.

There are lots of options to play with, to style and position the annotation exactly as you wish.

This will only work if `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js"></script>` has been included.

```js
var investment = 10000;
Highcharts.chart('updown_chart', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.series[0].data.length; i++) {
          if (this.series[0].data[i].y == null && this.series[1].data[i].y == null) {
            this.addAnnotation({
              labelOptions: {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
                borderWidth: 0,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 0
              },
              labels: [{
                point: {
                  x: i,
                  y: 0,
                  xAxis: 0,
                 yAxis: 0
                },
                text: 'Your title here',
                shape: 'rect',
                style: {
                 fontSize: '20px'
                }
              }]
            })
          }
        }
        this.redraw()
      }
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['pa', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4'],
    reversed: false,
    labels: {
      step: 1
    }
  },
  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value + '%';
      }
    },

    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'center',
      formatter: function() {
        var newval = this.total;
        var pval = Math.abs(this.total);
        var amount = parseInt((investment * pval) / 100);
        if (this.isNegative) {
          newval = '-' + pval + '%' + ' ($' + amount + ')';
        } else {
          newval = '+' + pval + '%' + ' ($' + amount + ')';
        }
        return newval;
      }
    }
  }],

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
        this.series.name + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 2) + '%';
    }
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },

  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    name: 'aa',
    color: '#428bca',
    data: [10, 20, 10, null]
  }, {
    showInLegend: false,
    name: 'bb',
    color: '#15315A',
    data: [-10, -20, -30, null]
  }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/annotations.js"></script>
<div id="updown_chart">

</div>
```

**Working jsfiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/p4e0m1w6/4/